# What does attribute WCHAR Name[1] means in Windows Kernel?

Tags: c, windows, char, kernel, windows-kernel

I was wondering what does [this](https://github.com/KernelPanic-OpenSource/Win2K3_NT_public/blob/44221d017659d6050f490d4e4c749d2aca1899b4/internal/drivers/inc/ntddsnap.h) structure means

```
typedef struct _VOLSNAP_NAME {
  USHORT  NameLength;
  WCHAR   Name[1];
} VOLSNAP_NAME, *PVOLSNAP_NAME;
```

I'm not understanding why the structure has a **NameLength** value since the **Name** length seems to be always 1. 
I also don't get why is the **WCHAR Name[1]** size present : should'nt

```
WCHAR Name;
```

be enough ?

Comment: Almost certainly there are extra name chars right after the structure.

Comment: The length is specified before allocation of an object, and the extra memory is allocated with `malloc(sizeof(_VOLSNAP_NAME) + length needed)`

Comment: It might be the old "struct hack". The Windows API predates C99 and the struct hack was used here and there, iirc also in bitmap headers and similar.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a define named `ANYSIZE_ARRAY` that you also see in similar structs and its value is 1. Both `[1]` and `[ANYSIZE_ARRAY]` are used when the array size is not known at compile time. This scheme was invented long before C99 added support for variable length arrays. `[0]` would perhaps make more sense but it is not legal syntax.

To work with those structures you often first call the desired API to get the size of the data, then allocate a block of memory big enough and finally call the same API again so it can fill in the data.

See also:

- [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://web.archive.org/web/20120209061713/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/26/220873.aspx)

Comment: *[0] would perhaps make more sense but it is not legal syntax.* some compilers (how minimum *CL* ) support `WCHAR   Name[];` syntax